# How does the Bitcoin Algorithm for Converting to Base 58 Work?

Tags: base-conversion

I've been trying to create a function in TypeScript for converting to and from base58. I'm pretty familiar with base conversion generally: divide a number by a target base, and take each remainder as a digit of the conversion from right to left, until it equals 0.

But this took me into Bitcoin's source code, which does the base 58 conversion in a way I've never seen before, working from a stream of bytes from left-to-right instead of the way I'm used to.

Here's their function for encoding to base 58:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/base58.cpp#L87

Essentially, for each byte in the input buffer, it sets a variable `carry` to the value of that byte. Then working from the end of the zero-filled output buffer, it multiplies that byte by 256 and adds it to `carry`. It sets the output byte to `carry %58` and sets `carry` to `carry / 58` (integer division). It then moves back one byte and repeats until `carry` is 0.

Here's the loop as I have it written in TypeScript:

```
    let base58Bytes = Buffer.alloc(size);
    let length = 0;

    while (input.length > 0) {
      let carry: number = input[0];
      let i = 0;

      for (
        let pos = base58Bytes.length - 1;
        (carry !== 0 || i < length) && pos >= 0;
        i++, pos--
      ) {
        carry += base58Bytes[pos] * 256;
        base58Bytes[pos] = carry % 58;
        carry = Math.floor(carry / 58);
      }

      length = i;
      input = input.subarray(1);
    }
```

My problem:

I see **that** it works, but not **why** it works. Any time I google base conversion, I find the first method I discussed, but nothing about this method.

In particular, I don't understand why the output byte is multiplied by the source base (256 in this case) before being added to `carry`.

I can see it works from any base to any base, and have worked it out by hand multiple times. I just don't understand why it works yet nor can I find any resources that explain it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by "source base being 256"?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Basically it takes the input as a stream of bytes. And every byte has 256 possible values (0x00-0xff), so that's essentially a base-256 value.